# Venting Plumbing AFTER drywall is up

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drywall, drain-waste-vent, rough-in

**First, some set up:**
My friends and I have been building a sort of Mancave over the last year.  It's about 300 square feet, with a height of about 14 feet -- half of the place has a loft (making something like 2 floors) while the other half has tall ceilings.

We initially did not have plans to put in a bathroom -- so, we put drywall up everywhere.  THEN, we decided it would be nice to have a bathroom.  We ran all of the water lines from city water up into the crawlspace (passing inspection), but now are preparing to tackle the bathroom.

**My question:**
With the drywall up, and roof shingled -- and the whole place basically ready for use.. we are putting a bathroom in.  Under the loft, we have built a 2x6 dividing wall for all of the plumbing to sit inside (just the studs right now).  HOWEVER -- we did not realize, being newbies, that you need a plumbing vent stack.  The question is, can we possibly vent our plumbing for an entire bathroom WITHOUT penetrating the roof?

There is a somewhat tall crawlspace under the building.  Could the drain just be low in the crawlspace, and have a vent that angles out through the rim joist and run the vent outside?  I have read that it is possible to vent through an exterior wall -- but as this 2x6 wall is in the middle of the house, reaching an outside wall might be difficult.

***What is my best option?***
I really appreciate any help!!

P.S.  I will be making sure any plans pass inspection before doing the plumbing -- Any help I get will go toward my plans.

Answer (score 1):

To vent plumbing you must either find a way to tie into an existing stack vent, go to the outside via wall (this is code depending on area and must be higher than all fixtures - what you are describing is not), or go through roof.

If the roof is available this is probably your easiest option.  You drill a hole and throw a [roofing vent](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Perma-Boot-4-in-Inside-Diameter-Black-New-Construction-or-Reroof-Thermoplastic-Vent-Pipe-Roof-Flashing-PB-312-4BK/203310754?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CTHD%7CG%7C0%7CG-BASE-PLA-D22-Roofing%7C&gclid=CLSnpabq5c8CFY-FaQod8m8DJg&gclsrc=aw.ds) with gasket over the hole, caulk gasket, plug pipe in bottom of vent through hole and you are done.  This is a very easy, forgiving process.   With materials in hand you can do this in 30 mins.  So just do it right.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your local codes, one might use a studer vent at the end of a short vent pipe (higher than any sink bowls/toilet resevoirs in the basement).  Such a vent isn't allowed to be within a closed off space (ie. within a wall) ...as there's be no make-up air.